# jQuery combining focus and hover

Tags: jquery, events, focus, hover

I am trying to use focus event on list element. it's working with hover, but not with focus! Do you have a idea  ?

```
$('#main-menu ul.rubriques li')
.hover(function() {
$(this).addClass('active').find('ul').show();                    
})
.focus(function() {
$(this).addClass('active').find('ul').show();                    
});
```

i try to modify my code: and find the solution ;) ;) ;)

```
  $('#main-menu ul.rubriques li a')
.hover(function() { $(this).parent().addClass('active').find('ul').show();                   
})
.focus(function() { $(this).parent().addClass('active').find('ul').show();                   
});
```

thanks ! everybody !

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis before `.focus`. Would that be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Focus is for `<input/>` elements and `<a/>` links...

Comment: or links anchors textareas =)

Comment: that is not only it, add tab-index attribute, and see google search results on how it is used

Comment: i add `$('#main-menu ul.rubriques li a')`
it's working only a problem, that's expand all my submenu ;)
`.focus(function() {
$('#main-menu ul.rubriques li').addClass('active').find('ul').show();`

Comment: @boby212 - that's because you are now selecting all the `li`'s. Without knowing you exact html, you need to do something like `$(this).parent().addClass('active').find('ul').show();`

Comment: thanks a lot, i just find the solution before you give it to me :p

Answer (score 2):

Only `inputs`, `textareas` and `anchors` can get focus.

Also, you're missing a `)` after the `hover()` part

```
$('#main-menu ul.rubriques li').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').find('ul').show();                    
}).focus(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').find('ul').show();                    
});
```

**Update** - as pointed out by [@vittore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274336/jquery-combining-focus-and-hover/5274438#5274438), `li`'s can get focus if you assign a `tab-index`

Comment: @boby212 - that's because `li` elements can't get focus. see my edit

Comment: they can if you add tab-index, see google search result for example

Answer (score 2):

You can also bind both events at once:

```
$('#main-menu ul.rubriques li').bind('hover focus', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').find('ul').show();                    
});
```

But like michelgotta says the focus is unlikely to work on an li except in some circumstances - http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Answer (score 1):

Focus is a function that you use only on form elements like input field for example, if I remember rightly.

http://api.jquery.com/focus/

What are you trying to do?

If you waht to do something with the li element use;

```
$('#main-menu ul.rubriques li').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active').find('ul').show().css({'border':'1px solid #ff2200','background-color':'#ffcc00'});
});
```

You can change the colors to whatever you want. That's your best alternative.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the way you assign handler as Geoff supposed, also you will need to explicitly set tab-index attribute for you list items in order to allow them fire focus event

Answer (score 0):

I try to modify my code: and find the solution ;) ;) ;)

```
  $('#main-menu ul.rubriques li a')
.hover(function() { $(this).parent().addClass('active').find('ul').show();                   
})
.focus(function() { $(this).parent().addClass('active').find('ul').show();                   
});
```

thanks ! everybody !